# How to align icon and text

Tags: css

I have added "WebSiteVoice" https://websitevoice.com/ to my site. I adjusted the code and have been able to place the icon where I want it with some text. However, when I view it in responsive mode, the location and text move and can be hard to read. Any ideas of how to manipulate this code for phones, etc.?

**ADDED: I need the text in a *horizontal* position, like the top one here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUAmH.jpg**

This is the code I am using:

```
.wv-wrapper.wv-circle-small {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.wv-wrapper.wv-circle-small::after {
  content: ' Listen to article ...';
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Examples can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUAmH.jpg

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML code as well?

Comment: I'm not sure how you guys think this is a duplicate. I am asking about the placement of something in different resolutions, not how to place a title next to a picture.

Comment: I don't exactly see how these are considered the same question either. You can try asking the question again, this time including the HTML code as well, as it is not entirely clear what these two CSS classes control specifically. It might also be helpful to see the containing elements and the other elements that it is interacting with (the text that gets covered on mobile).